# I have a list Contacts that appears twice on a page and I only want to add a button to the list in the second occurrence of the list/app

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I have a custom list called contacts that appears on a WIKI Page twice (next to each other). On the first instance (the left) will be a list of contacts that have a hyperlink to a RACI page.  On the second instance (the right), I have a list of maybe two contacts that are the result of a view that will display a list of support contacts.

The script that I have developed will find the contacts list and append a button to send an email to the applicable contact.  This same script will add the button to the first instance as well.  I only want my script to affect the second instance.

My script is:

```
var subjectType="";
var bodyText="";
$(document).ready(function() {  

    // Get the subject type
    var this_js_script = $('script[src*=AddContactButtons]');
    subjectType = this_js_script.attr('data-Subject'); 
    if (typeof subjectType == 'undefined' || subjectType == null || subjectType == ''){
      subjectType = "Site";
    }
    //console.log('subjectType='+subjectType);
    buttonLabel = this_js_script.attr('data-Button'); 
    if (typeof buttonLabel == 'undefined' || buttonLabel == null || buttonLabel == ''){
      buttonLabel = "Help";
    }
    //console.log('buttonLabel='+buttonLabel);
    bodyText = this_js_script.attr('data-BodyText'); 
    if (typeof bodyText == 'undefined' || bodyText == null || bodyText == ''){
      bodyText = "";
    }
    //console.log('bodyText='+bodyText);
    buttoncolor = this_js_script.attr('data-ButtonColor'); 
    if (typeof buttoncolor == 'undefined' || buttoncolor == null || buttoncolor == ''){
      buttoncolor = "#004d99";
    }
    //console.log('buttoncolor='+buttoncolor);
    buttontextcolor = this_js_script.attr('data-ButtonTextColor'); 
    if (typeof buttontextcolor == 'undefined' || buttontextcolor == null || buttontextcolor == ''){
      buttontextcolor = "white";
    }
    //console.log('buttontextcolor='+buttontextcolor);
    addContactButtons(subjectType,bodyText,buttoncolor,buttontextcolor);
});
function addContactButtons(subjectType,bodyText,buttoncolor,buttontextcolor){
    var listTitle="Contacts";
    //console.log('addcontactButtons:subjectType='+subjectType);
    //console.log('addcontactButtons:bodyText='+bodyText);
    //console.log('addcontactButtons:buttoncolor='+buttoncolor);
    $("table.ms-listviewtable[summary='"+listTitle+"']>tbody>tr").each(function(){
        $(this).append("<input type='button' value='"+buttonLabel+"' style='background-color:"+buttoncolor+"; color:"+buttontextcolor+"' class='btnSub' onclick='javascript:openMail(this);'>");
    });
}
function openMail(btn){
    var emailString = "mailto:";
    var emailID = $(btn).prev("td").text()
    var URL = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    //console.log('openMail:subjectType='+subjectType);
    //console.log('openMail:bodyText='+bodyText);
    //console.log('openMail:URL='+URL);

    emailString += emailID ;
    if (subjectType == 'Site'){
        emailString += "?Subject=SharePoint Site Support - Site=";
        //emailString += _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
    } else {
        emailString += "?Subject="+subjectType;
    }
    if (bodyText != ''){
        emailString += "&Body="+bodyText;
    }
    var finalEmailString = emailString.replace(/Site=/,"Site="+URL);
    //console.log(finalEmailString);
    location.href=finalEmailString;
}
```

What can I do to limit the scope of the script to only the second instance of the App Part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$("tbody>tr","table.ms-listviewtable[summary='MyList']:eq(1)").each(function () {
                $(this).append("<input type='button' value='value' class='btnSub' onclick='javascript:openMail(this);'/>");
            });
```

[image]